# How to combine places from Google Places and my own places in my Android app

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

My app needs to show in recyclerview Clubs and Partys near the current location of the user. In order to support all nightclubs and Bars I need an option to let the user add manually nightclubs if it's not already exists.
I need them to have the same look and feel as the Places I get from Google. What would you recommend, create my own database and store all the Bars and Nightclubs details from Google Places and custom Bars -OR- load the data from Google every time the user is searching and add the custom places from my database? Any other ideas will be appreciated too.

Comment: Assume a new place would be continuously added/removed from Google results... Would you then periodically reload your database? When you search things, would it make sense to populate a database from those results? Data can get stale. Point being : searching + loading local results seems ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocoding is the answer to your question: https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. that's​ very useful.

Comment: You're welcome :)
EDIT: Maybe mark the answer as correct, so that other users know when they search for it.